# What kind of grammar is this? Question without question form?

Tags: questions, question-tags

"That's why you did this!?"

That's obvious a question, but no question form is used? Shouldn't it be something like

"is that why you did this?"

Comment: No, because both examples contain embedded questions (interrogative content clauses): "That's _why you did this_?!; "Is that _why you did this_? The meanings are "That's the answer to the question 'Why did you do this?"' and "Is that the answer to the question 'Why did you do this?"'

Answer (score 0):

The two punctuation marks (!?) are not standard, but they do show the speaker's surprise. You could skip the exclamation mark and leave yourself with a **rhetorical question** (you appear to ask a question but really express an opinion.)

[Definition from Collins English Dictionary, 12th Ed.:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rhetorical+question)

> A question to which no answer is required: used esp for dramatic effect. An example is *Who knows?* (implying that *Nobody knows*)

The two sentences mean the same, with different feelings.

- 1 expresses shock or anger, as in "Please do not tell me you had that reason for doing this bad thing, because I do not appreciate your actions."
- 2 simply seeks information in "Is that why?"